# When Using Bootstrap / html is it alright to use empty divs or spans as placeholders in the grid?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Just working with bootstrap and was wondering if it was okay to use empty div or spans as placeholders to make my grid work the way I want.

For example

```
 <header class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"></div> <!-- is this ok? -->
     <div class="col-md-8">Some Content</div>
 </header>
```

Right now I am trying not to use empty divs but use the offset class but I would like to put the offset on the right side instead of the left is that possible?

Comment: of course it is possible. offsets are meant for pushing columns to the right (on a left-to-right layout). i you're using offsets, you don't have any problem to begin with.

Comment: Since the `col-md-8` is 8 parts of a 12 column grid it already has a right side offset of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but have you tried this:

```
<header class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4"></div>
</header>
```